# how to get passport.authenticate local strategy working with async/await pattern

Tags: node.js, async-await, passport-local, passport.js

I've been failing to get passport.authenticate to work at all inside of an async/await or promise pattern. Here is an example I feel should work, but it fails to execute passport.authenticate().

```
const passport = require("passport");

let user;

try {
    user = await __promisifiedPassportAuthentication();

    console.log("You'll never have this ", user);
} catch (err) {
    throw err;
}

function __promisifiedPassportAuthentication() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        console.log("I run");

        passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {

            console.log("I never run");

            if (err) reject(err);
            if (user) resolve(user);
        }
    }
}
```

Any sage words of wisdom would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just incase any other tired programmer out there encounters this..

```
function __promisifiedPassportAuthentication() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
            ...
        })(req, res) // <-- that guy right there
    }
}
```

Comment: Missing a `)` before `(req, res)`

Comment: Shouldn't `req` and `res` be passed to `promisifiedPassportAuthentication`?

Comment: Wow, I was stuck on this for ages. Thanks a lot!

Comment: upvoted! cant you use util.promisify on this instead of duplicating the entire method inside a promise?

Comment: I'm running the following and I'm getting "Reference error: req is not defined" -------   function promisifiedPassportAuthentication() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      passport.authenticate('spotify', { failureRedirect: '/login' }, (err, user, info) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        if (user) resolve(user);
      })(req, res)
  })
}

Comment: without passing "next", (req, res, next) it does not work for me, because it doesn't log you in.