# How to setup authentication with graphql, and passport but still use Playground

Tags: express, graphql, passport.js, apollo-server, passport-azure-ad

After adding authentication to our backend Graphql server the "Schema" and "Docs" are no longer visible in the Graphql Playground. Executing queries when adding a token to the "HTTP HEADERS" in the Playground does work correctly when authenticated and not when a user isn't authenticated, so that's ok.

We disabled the built-in Playground from Apollo-server and used the middleware `graphql-playground-middleware-express` to be able to use a different URL and bypass authentication. We can now browse to the Playground and use it but we can't read the "Schema" or "Docs" there.

Trying to enable `introspection` didn't fix this. Would it be better to call `passport.authenticate()` in the `Context` of `apollo-server`? There's also a tool called [passport-graphql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-passport) but it works with local strategy and might not solve the problem. I've also [tried setting the token in the header](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1982) before calling the Playground route, but that didn't work.

We're a bit lost at this. Thank you for any insights you could give us.

[image]

The relevant code:

```js
// index/ts
import passport from 'passport'
import expressPlayground from 'graphql-playground-middleware-express'

const app = express()
app.use(cors({ origin: true }))
app.get('/playground', expressPlayground({ endpoint: '/graphql' }))
app.use(passport.initialize())
passport.use(bearerStrategy)

app.use(
  passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', { session: false }),
  (req, _res, next) => { next() }
)
;(async () => {
    await createConnections()
    const server = await new ApolloServer({
      schema: await getSchema(),
      context: ({ req }) => ({ getUser: () => req.user, }),
      introspection: false,
      playground: false,
    })
    server.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: false })

    app.listen({ port: ENVIRONMENT.port }, () => { console.log(`Server ready`) })      
})()
```

```js
// passport.ts
import { IBearerStrategyOptionWithRequest, BearerStrategy, ITokenPayload } from passport-azure-ad'
import { Account } from '@it-portal/entity/Account'

export const bearerStrategy = new BearerStrategy( config,
  async (token: ITokenPayload, done: CallableFunction) => {
    try {
      if (!token.oid) throw 'token oid missing'

      const knownAccount = await Account.findOne({ accountIdentifier: token.oid })
      if (knownAccount) return done(null, knownAccount, token)

      const account = new Account()
      account.accountIdentifier = token.oid
      account.name = token.name
      account.userName = (token as any).preferred_username
      const newAccount = await account.save()
      return done(null, newAccount, token)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Failed adding the user to the request object: ${error}`)
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885983/secure-graphql-queries-with-express-js-passport-s). The key was not to use `passport` as middleware on Express but rather use it in the Graphql `Context`.

In the example code below you can see the Promise `getUser`, which does the passport authentication, being used in the `Context` of ApolloServer. This way the Playground can still be reached and the "Schema" end "Docs" are still accessible when run in `dev` mode.

This is also the preferred way according to the Apollo [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/security/authentication/) section "Putting user info on the context".

```js
// apollo.ts
passport.use(bearerStrategy)

const getUser = (req: Express.Request, res: Express.Response) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', { session: false }, (err, user) => {
      if (err) reject(err)
      resolve(user)
    })(req, res)
  })

const playgroundEnabled = ENVIRONMENT.mode !== 'production'

export const getApolloServer = async () => {
  return new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context: async ({ req, res }) => {
      const user = await getUser(req, res)
      if (!user) throw new AuthenticationError('No user logged in')
      console.log('User found', user)

      return { user }
    },
    introspection: playgroundEnabled,
    playground: playgroundEnabled,
  })
}
```

The best thing is that you only need two functions for this to work: `passport.use(BearerStrategy)` and `passport.authenticate()`. This is because sessions are not used so we don't need to add it as Express middleware.

```js
// index/ts
const app = express()
app.use(cors({ origin: true }))

;(async () => {
    await createConnections()
    const server = await getApolloServer()
    server.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: false })

    app.listen({ port: ENVIRONMENT.port }, () => { console.log(`Server ready`) })      
})()
```

I hope this helps others with the same issues.